# How do you make a 404 page for every non-existant subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, 404

I have a site `http://example.com` how do you make a 404 page for subdomains that do not exist?

e.g if I was to try and visit `a-sub-domain-that-does-not-exist.stackexchange.com` I get a 404 page.

The default behavior for subdomains is that they don't resolve.  I would instead like to create a user-friendly "not found" page for them.

Comment: If you have not set-up your web server yet, the first thing you may want to do is create a catch-all website. This would do the trick I think and something that should be done anyway. The reason why it is the first site is so it will respond to IP based requests too. From there, you can use an .htaccess or equivalent wildcard to redirect all invalid sub-domain requests to a specific page if you want.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: Assuming Linux and Apache, the very first site you set-up will respond to the IP address of the machine. If you do not assign a domain name to this site and create a new site for your domain name, then the first site captures all IP address based accesses and any domain based access that Apache does not have a site for (theoretically). This is known as a catch-all site. You can create a web page and leave it at that or set up an .htaccess file in this site that handles all sub-domain.domain.tld requests and redirects to another page if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I am making the assumption that you will be defining a catch all dns record for your domain, eg: `*.example.com IN A 1.1.1.1` so that all sub domains of example.com that are not specifically mentioned will be routed to the web server. In this instance this would be handled by your server code. All you would do is detect the domain name, if the requested sub domain does not exist then you would send a HTTP 404 header and output a standard HTML page stating that the site requested does not exist. This would both present a friendly page for the user to see the site doesnt exist as well as sending the correct headers so that Google and other automated systems detect that the site doesn't exist and don't try indexing your error page.

As a side note you only need to do this if you are using wildcard DNS entries. If you will be defining each and every DNS entry manually then there is no need to do this part as if a DNS record is requested that doesn't exist the browser automatically returns an error message saying that the requested domain name doesn't exist.